# Illegal string offset 'name' error calling component from blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

In my Laravel 8 app I created new component with command

```
php artisan make:component  Admin/Auth/loggedUserHasPermissions
```

and I have error with sending parameter to it from blade file :

```
Illegal string offset 'name' (View: /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/AdsBackend8/resources/views/test.blade.php)
```

On row in resources/views/test.blade.php :

```
<x-logged-user-has-permissions :logged-user="getLoggedUser()" />
```

getLoggedUser is funnction in helper file.

and in app/View/Components/Admin/Auth/loggedUserHasPermissions.php

```
<?php

namespace App\View\Components\Admin\Auth;

use Illuminate\View\Component;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role;

class loggedUserHasPermissions extends Component
{
    private $loggedUser;
    private $hasAdminRole;
    public function __construct($loggedUser)
    {
        $this->loggedUser = $loggedUser;
        $this->hasAdminRole = false;

    }

    public function render()
    {
```

I follow  camelCase / kebab-case rules written here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#passing-data-to-components
running commands

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan route:cache
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan  clear-compiled

composer dump-autoload
```

did not help

How it can be fixed?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the code for your `test.blade.php` file?

Comment: I provided it above:         <x-logged-user-has-permissions :logged-user="getLoggedUser()" />
I suppose that sign ":" make content rendered as php

Comment: Replace `public function __construct($loggedUser)` with `public function mount($loggedUser)` and see if it fixes it. In LiveWire components, the construct is replaced by the mount() method.

Comment: That is not LiveWire components project. The link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#passing-data-to-components is common core laravel . Or not ?

Comment: does the blade file locate the component correctly? it has to be `<x-admin.auth.logged-user-has-permissions  .../>
`

Comment: Thanks, that is the point